# What is the use of -r or --require command-line option in node javascript-runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js

Namasthe Team,

What is the use of -r or --require command-line option in nodejs javascript-runtime?

How does it work?

Can you help me with some working examples beyond what is mentioned in https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/cli.html

Regards,
Ramu Mohan Srinivasan Radhakrishnan

Following are the contents of my /run/user/1000/circle.js

```
#! /opt/node-v20.6.0-linux-x64/bin/node

'use strict';

function areaOfCircle( circleRadius ) {
  return Math.PI * ( circleRadius * circleRadius );
}

export areaOfCircle
```

I start the node command with following

```
node -r ${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/circle.js
```

and I am presented with following

```
areaOfCircle is not defined
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you get just `areaOfCircle is not defined` with that? I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` since that's not valid (plain) JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`-r` is used to load a module before your user code runs.
You're not supposed to generally do (e.g.) `node -r circle.js` (unless you really know what you're doing); just do `node circle.js`

A fairly common use example for `-r` is [ts-node's `-r ts-node/register`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#node-flags-and-other-tools), which lets `ts-node` hook into Node before your TypeScript code would execute.

In a similar vein, and to demonstrate what `-r` does with some plain code, given a `hook.js` that's

```
const origLog = console.log;
console.log = (...args) => origLog("I AM LOGGING!!!", ...args);
```

and a `code.js` that's just

```
console.log("Hello!");
```

then running `node` with the hook `-r`equired prints out

```
$ node -r ./hook.js code.js
I AM LOGGING!!! Hello!
```

(even if `code.js` itself didn't `require` the hook).